# Crystal Reports not able to print '&' character

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, special-characters

I am retrieving data from an SQL stored procedure and displaying it in a text field in a pdf document created with Crystal Reports.

The problem is whenever the data contains an '&' character it only displays the text before that character.

It is being stored in the SQL table as the actual character '&' and when the query is executed the SQL result set shows the correct character as well as when it is being displayed in a browser. But when the report is ran and the same data is being retrieved, Crystal Reports is not able to display the character.

Is there a way to tell Crystal Reports to display the character?

Using SQL Server 2000 with Visual Studio 2008 and Crystal Reports Basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I determined that the text with the ampersand was being passed to the page that was creating my Crystal Report through the URL. I used the javascript function encodeURIComponent('&') to replace the ampersand with the '%26' value and when it reached the Crystal Report it was being read as an ampersand and not as a URL variable which was messing everything up.

Answer (score 0):

the ampersand character is the crystal syntax for concatenation, you have to put the & into double quotes to show it on your report.

Comment: I've tried using the double quotes around the ampersand as well as single quotes and it only prints the first set of quotes before the ampersand and then cuts the string there. I also tried putting an escape character '\&' but that did not work as well...any other suggestions?